# Rails Call 'Create' Action from Another Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, I'm attempting to create a notification system where notifications will be created automatically when certain controller actions are called. I have the following 'create' action in the notifications controller:

```
def create
    @notification = Notification.new(notification_params)
    @notification.save

end
```

I need to call this action from other controller actions, and pass different parameter values to it depending on which controller action calls it. After creating the new notification, I need to continue running code in the controller action that calls it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this method to application_controller.rb and allow to pass params to it.

Then you'll be able to call it from any controller method